# Get the assembly project file name from Output TaskParameter

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am using `msbuild.exe` to automate my build from the command line.

I do the following steps.

- Compile projects into a folder each outside the project directory
- zip every compiled project

here are my targets

first one to compile

```
<Target Name="BuildProjects"  DependsOnTargets="BeforeBuild">

    <ItemGroup>      
  <BuildProjectFiles Include="**\MyCompany.Project1\MyCompany.Project1.csproj" />
  <BuildProjectFiles Include="**\MyCompany.Project2\MyCompany.Project2.csproj" />
  <BuildProjectFiles Include="**\MyCompany.Project2\MyCompany.Project2-CE.csproj" />
      ... and some more
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild Projects="@(BuildProjectFiles)" Properties="AllowUnsafeBlocks=true;Configuration=$(Configuration);OutputPath=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Deploy\bin\%(BuildProjectFiles.FileName)">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"
                ItemName="BuildProjectsOutputFiles" />
    </MSBuild>

</Target>
```

and now the target to zip every compiled project to its one file.

```
<Target Name="ZipProjects" DependsOnTargets="BuildProjects">

    <CreateItem
        Include="@(BuildProjectOutputFiles)"
            AdditionalMetadata="AssemblyName=%(Filename);ProjectName=%(RelativeDir)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="BuildProjectsOutputFiles123"/>
    </CreateItem>

    <CreateItem Include="%(BuildProjectsOutputFiles123.RelativeDir)*" AdditionalMetadata="OutputFileName=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Deploy\dist\$(Configuration)\%(BuildProjectsOutputFiles123.AssemblyName)-$(MajorNumber).$(MinorNumber).$(ReleaseNumber).zip;WorkingDirectory=%(BuildProjectsOutputFiles123.RelativeDir)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="BuildProjectsOutputFiles456"/>
    </CreateItem>

    <Zip Files="@(BuildProjectsOutputFiles456)"
        WorkingDirectory="%(BuildProjectsOutputFiles456.WorkingDirectory)" 
        ZipFileName="%(BuildProjectOutputFiles456.OutputFileName)"  />
        <!-- ZipLevel="9"/> -->

</Target>
```

So what happens is that every project I specified in `BuildProjectFiles` gets compiled into the folder `<rootdir>\deploy\bin\<name of the csproj file without extension\`

In the second step I use the `MSBuild.Community.Tasks` Zip-Task to zip every project and copy it to `<rootdir>\deploy\dist\release\<assemblyname>-<version>.zip`

So basically the assembly `project1.exe` and its dependencies are in the file `project1-2.4.7.zip` after executing msbuild.

That works very well. But now I have a change that I can't figure out how solve. I have two assemblys with the same assembly name (one for Windows and the other for Windows CE) so the first project compiles and creates a folder `project2-2.4.7.zip` and then the next project compiles and overwrites the zip file.

Now I want the Zip-File to be named after the `.csproj` file (like the bin folder).
Since my one project file is called `mycompany.project2.csproj` and the other one `mycompany.project2-ce.csproj` I should be fine.

In short: How can I pass the project name to the zip target?

Answer (score 1):

Is this suitable? 
$(MSBuildProjectName)

[MSBuild Reserved Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx)

Comment: No, since my targets are located in the file `build.targets` this would generate a `build-2.4.7.zip` file (for every project and overwrite the previous file). But thanks for sharing the link, could be useful in the future. What I really need is to pass `%(BuildProjectsInputFiles.FileName)` to `BuildProjectsOutputFiles` so I can acces it from `BuildProjectsOutputFiles123`